# Stop NSTimer and dismiss view controller (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, viewcontroller

I am using `NSTimer` to look for updates in my `firebase` database. I have put the code inside my `viewDidLoad()`.

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(DriversInterfaceViewController.CheckFormularChild), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

When the user has received a file in the database I want the user to goto another `ViewController`. The problem is that either the old `ViewController` is running in the background or the timer does not stop when changing `View Controller`.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)            
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("recievedMission") as! RecievedMissionViewController
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

How do I dismiss the old `View Controller` or how do I stop the `NSTimer` `programmatically`? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just store the instance of your timer and then when you are moving to another Controller invalidate the timer, so that first declare one instance of `NSTimer`.

```
var timer:NSTimer?
```

Now use this object to store the reference of your scheduledTimer.

```
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(DriversInterfaceViewController.CheckFormularChild), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Now on moving to another controller simply.

```
self.timer.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var timer:NSTimer?

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: 
    #selector(DriversInterfaceViewController.CheckFormularChild), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    //ToStop Timer

    timer.invalidate()
    timer = nil
```

It's a good thing to nil the instance variable timer after having invalidated it, it avoids further confusion if you need to create another timer with the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

When the NSTimer hasn't invalidated yet, the instance of view controller is stil in memory and hasn't been released in ARC. So you need to  invalidate the NSTimer when the old view controller disappears.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) 
{
   if self.timer != nil
   {
      self.timer!.invalidate()
      self.timer = nil
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Hi, after timer event completion you need to invalidate that timer as like as follow

```
yourTimer.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 0):

To cancel a NSTimer, just use:

```
timer?.invalidate()
```

And please make sure your function `DriversInterfaceViewController.CheckFormularChild` runs in UIThread (If this method touches UI) or else it'll crash